# How to integrate Headway changelog in gatsby app?

Tags: gatsby

https://docs.headwayapp.co/widget

this is the below code i want to paste i created html.js to add third party script but not able to fix it https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

```
<script>
  var HW_config = {
    selector: ".CHANGE_THIS", // CSS selector where to inject the badge
    account: "ACCOUNT_ID" // your account ID, you can find it in Settings->Widget
  };
</script>
<script async src="//cdn.headwayapp.co/widget.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several approaches and workarounds to achieve this. One of them could be creating an isolated component named `<HeadwayWidget>` and import it to your page/component. You'll need to add a `componentDidMount` lifecycle to ensure that your DOM tree is loaded. In addition, in Gatsby, you will need to check for the [`document` availability](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/) since at the time you are requesting it may not be created yet.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class HeadwayWidget extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      let script, config;
       if(typeof document !== undefined){
        script = document.createElement("script");
        script.async = true;
        script.src = "https://cdn.headwayapp.co/widget.js";
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        config = {
            selector: ".headway-badge",
            account: "Your_Headway_ID"
        };
        script.onload = function() {
            window.Headway.init(config)
        }
      }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <span className="headway-badge" id="headway-badge">
                    What's New
                </span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

There's a lack of information about your trials but, in the approach above, you are using a stateful component. Of course, you can transpile it to a stateless component, by changing the `componentDidMount` by `useEffect` hook (with empty deps, `[]`).